# Elastic Beanstalk: Rolling Updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Do rolling updates control (honor the wait time between the push to instances) minor updates to application like "Changing a header field of a jsp page".

I have set up the rolling update time to 1 hour and i have four instances. I am using eclipse IDE. I make a minor change on header/title bar and then click "Run on Server" in AWS EC2 APACHE TOMCAT7 (US-EAST-1). Beanstalk goes and updates all 4 instances at once. I was expecting it to wait for 1 hour each and all instances  updated after 3 hours.. But it happens instantaneously..

Comment: If you want zero downtime during deployments, you should follow the instructions here: [Deploying Versions with Zero Downtime](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rolling updates are not supported in beanstalk for app version changes.. They are supported for only env changes..  See the blogs below.. As on today web deployments or version updates cause a brief downtime because beanstalk updates all servers at once..

- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=502158&#502158
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=328344&#328344
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=506438&#506438

You can do something like this:
    https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=258782

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Elastic Beanstalk now provides rolling **deploys** for your purposes.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.rolling-version-deploy.html

As opposed to rolling **updates**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.rollingupdates.html

Deploys are for software changes while updates are for configuration changes. Elastic beanstalk now has a few different options for deploys so that you avoid downtime and also deploying an unhealthy software to production.